# Recommendations for cloud-based document sharing platform for small business

Tags: document-management, cloud-service

I'm looking for a good, cheap, cloud-based document sharing system for a small NGO (30-40 employees) that allows us to easily save documents under multiple files/filters/tags. That is, each document has a

- project name
- document type ("concept note," "policy memo," etc.)
- sector ("health," "education")
- sub-sector ("maternal health", "child health")
- country office

Ideally we would want a set of predefined tags that we could also nest under predefined categories.

Google Drive is fine for organizing files under one folder-based hierarchy but is a bit unwieldy when multiple tags are needed - I want this to be as easy/automated as possible, both on the uploading end (ideally you would be automatically prompted to select tags of each type) and on the browsing end (simple to choose which structure to search or browse by).

The closest thing I've found so far is [SmartBins](https://www.smartbins.net/), but it doesn't seem to allow for nested folders (which they call "tag clouds") and the file upload feature isn't working on my browser anyway. It's also $10/user/month, and given that we don't require a huge amount of space I wonder if there are cheaper options.

Answer (score 2):

You can carry on using Google Drive - documents can easily be a member of multiple folders;

1. Find the document for which folders you would like to change.
2. Right click, "move to"
3. Hold CTRL and click the folder memberships that you're after. You'll see multiple ticks appear in the folder selection dialog.